# best_in_place gem to edit currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using the [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem to edit balances:

index.html.erb:

```
<%= best_in_place bankaccount, :balance, :display_with => :number_to_currency %>
```

but after editing, I get a unformatted number ($45 changed to 46 shows as 46).

How do I get best_in_place to display the new value as $$$?

controller:

```
 respond_to :html, :json
...
def update
    @bankaccount = Bankaccount.find(params[:id])
    if @bankaccount.update_attributes(params[:bankaccount])
      respond_with @bankaccount
    else
      render :json =>  @bankaccount.errors.full_messages, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    end
    # if @bankaccount.update_attributes(params[:bankaccount])
    #       redirect_to @bankaccount, :notice  => "Successfully updated bankaccount."
    #     else
    #       render :action => 'edit'
    #     end
  end
```

Comment: Did you try `:helper_options => {:unit => "$"}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using BIP's  :display_as => :mk_bal with mk_bal defined in model Bankaccount as:

```
def mk_bal
    ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(self.balance, :precision => 2)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This thread is already answered but I tried the accepted answer and it didn't work.

However using a lambda everything is nice again. Rails 4, by the way.

```
<%= best_in_place @text, :body, :type => :textarea, :display_with => lambda{ |v| markdown(v) }, :html_attrs => { :class => 'edit-text-body' }  %>
```

Comment: Tried `= best_in_place resource, :price, activator: '#edit-resource-name', display_with => lambda{ |v| number_to_currency(v) }` and didn't work

Comment: I'm already having troubles with this as well. You should look the repo's issues, but it seems to be no solution.

Comment: True. Strange that it doesn't work since the `:display_with => :number_to_currency` is documented on the Github page.

Comment: Thanks Sebas, the lambda works very well with number_to_currency!